# Flex container doesn't expand when contents wrap in a column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-container (a `<ul>`) with its children set to wrap in a column. The issue I have is that once the children wrap, the background of the flex-container doesn't extend to cover these wrapped children.  Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/NickGard/pen/WreQEQ?editors=110) of the issue.

Here is the code from the pen:

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 8em;
  /*to force wrapping*/
  background-color: #999;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ul>
```

#### Edit:

In my real use-case, I don't know how tall the flex-container will be **or** how many children it will have, so it will wrap at different points.

Comment: Huh, I did not know about this. Affects `outline` and `border` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You're setting `display: flex` but not setting a flex value on the children. Instead of `width: 3em`, it should be something like `flex: 1`, depending on what you're trying to achieve. Using `display: flex` but then defining a width in `em` doesn't make sense.

**Edit: Not sure why it was downvoted, can the downvoter clarify? The problem in the question would be resolved with proper use of positioning (e.g. use a `flex` value instead of setting a `width`).**

Comment: Unfortunately, in my real use-case, I won't know how tall the `<ul>` will be, so it will wrap at different places.  I'll add this detail to the original question.