# flex-flow: column wrap, in a flex box causing overflow of parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this scenario:

https://jsfiddle.net/b6zcdgf7/

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  height:3em;
  border:solid thin blue;
}
.section{
  border:solid thin gray;
  display:flex;
}
.section.horiz{
  
}

.section.vert{
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
  border:solid thin red;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section horiz">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section horiz">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section horiz">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section vert">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When using `.section.vert` the `.box` elements overflow the section.

Is there anything i can do to prevent having to set a width on the `.section.vert` element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width)

Comment: Based on that post. Its a known issue that hasn't been fixed in every major browser?

Comment: Yes, it is a known issue and, to the best of my knowledge, there is currently no natural fix. See my answer in the dupe. I posted links to many other questions similar to yours. No solution provided anywhere. It's strange because all browsers behave the same, which suggests this is not a bug.  Maybe there's a technical reason (such as implementation difficulty) for this deficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `flex-wrap` to `nowrap`

```
.section.vert{
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  outline: 3px dashed green;

}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/hhwwgcuz/)

**Snippet**

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  height:3em;
  border:solid thin blue;
}
.section{
  border:solid thin gray;
  display:flex;
}
.section.horiz{
  
}

.section.vert{
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  outline: 3px dashed green;

}

.box{
  border:solid thin red;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section horiz">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section horiz">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section horiz">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section vert">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like the OP wants them to wrap, but have the container expand to contain them.