# Flexbox background does not cover children on horizontal overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent container that has a (priori unknown) number of children that have a minimum width. When I resize the browser past the point of children shrinking, the parent background shrinks with the window, and does not cover children.

```css
.row{
    display:flex;
    background-color:#fcc;
    background-size:cover;
}
.row:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#fbb;
}
.child{
    min-width:150px;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="child"> content </div>
    <div class="child"> content </div>
    <div class="child"> content </div>
</div>
<!--more rows follow-->
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5s3n3g8/)

How would I go about ensuring the parent background covers all the children?

I tried putting `width:100%`, `background-size:cover` on the `.row` element. Also tried wrapping everything in a container and setting `overflow:auto` on that.

The only way I can sort of get it work is if i put `overflow:auto` on the .row element, but then it makes each row horizontally-scrollable independent of others.

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width) post, but it's not exactly what I need - I'm not wrapping any flex-items, the point is for them to stay the way they are.

I also read [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) article, but I can't see anything that can help with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `display: inline-flex;`

**Check:** https://jsfiddle.net/n5s3n3g8/1/