# flexbox vertically split container in HALF

Tags: css, flexbox

Can anyone tell how can I make **right top** container and **right bottom** container to have the same height and to split the red container 50-50% vertically. No matter what is the content inside. I tried stretching content and have them wrapped while keeping `flex-direction: row` to keep same height for items but I'm lost.

What I expect: **right top** container grows the same height as **right bottom** which also results the **left** container growing automatically of course.
[image: problem]

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/rozoxoneki/edit?html,css,output

```
.flex{
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
  &-child{
    background: green;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    flex: 1;
  }
}

.flex--vertical{
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  > .flex-child{
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}


<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child flex flex--vertical">
    <div class="flex-child">
      <h1>right top</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
      <h1>right bottom</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium autem esse iste voluptate eum ex mollitia temporibus unde eveniet omnis, vel, corrupti sed nobis consequatur quaerat ad sequi aliquid nostrum?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, you can't...that's not the way flexbox works. You can make the boxes *initially* the [**same size**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xVYyvy) but once content is added then the *flexy* part of flexbox comes into place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Intuitively one would expect that this would work just with a `flex-direction: column` for the main container and the left container's height set to 100%.

Instead all browser do this: (this is a quote from another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width))

> How is it possible that all major browsers got the flex container to
>   expand on wrap in row-direction but not in column-direction?

So what you can do is wrap the two right containers into a new one:

Like this HTML - schema:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left-container">Left container</div>
    <div class="right-container">
        <div class="half-containers">Top right</div>
        <div class="half-containers">Bottom right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrjx4zw/5/) as an example how you could style it for the expected result.

In this example the 'main-container' is set to 50% width and 75% height of the body.

Comment: Thanks, but it behaves the same as my example. Add some more text into one of the containers on right. It'll loose 50/50% distribution

Comment: Setting the max-height: 50% for the half-containers works in Firefox but not in Chrome. Another approach is to set the direction for the right container to rows with item widths of 100%, wrap them and explicitly setting every height to 50%. I updated the fiddle above. It works in Firefox, Chrome and IE. (IE needs max-width on every item - in case you wonder why it's there)

Answer (score 28):

**The accepted answer is not ideal** for the use of flex properties, because it can all be done without the need for `min-height` or `max-height`

I've cleaned up the [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kbxLtkb/1/) and removed non-essential css styles to show which flex properties are being used here.

In order to get evenly spaced top/bottom divs, you need to either specify the proper value for `flex-basis`, or let flex work itself out. Assuming that the parent's display is set to flex with a column orientation, the combined `flex` style can get us there easily:

```
.half-containers {
    flex: 1;
}
```

see more on [flex styling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the [`flex-basis`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/) property

Comment: should be the answer

Comment: The `overflow: auto` appears to be critical in getting this working.

Comment: Ooo, I like this. Places nice with `gap` too.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Felipe's answer, here is an even more minimal example of how to split a single flex container in half vertically. Each of these styles has been confirmed to be significant and necessary, except for the two at the bottom marked `optional`.

(What got me was that every parent element needs to have a `height: 100%` set, or the whole thing breaks.)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">This is the top.</div>
  <div class="row">This is the bottom.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
}

/* optional: get rid of body margin. makes look nice. */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* optional: shade the bottom row */
.row:nth-child(2) {
  background: #bbb
}
```

Working CodePen here:

https://codepen.io/rbrtmrtn/pen/NyxeJE

Comment: this doesn't work when you add more contents to one of divs, see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kxemog

Answer (score 0):

we can use flexbox concepts to split equally between two div with the parent in the following way

```css
* {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
 }
.row {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .col {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<title>Other page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae
    expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis
    laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```