# make 1 full container in left and half and half container in right

Tags: css

same like above example but in each container have text in middle and make responsive as well. anybody can help?

[flexbox vertically split container in HALF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568572/flexbox-vertically-split-container-in-half)

Comment: Did you try it yourself atleast? Show us your work and we'll help you out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here something that can give you a start:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 15em;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  background: red;
}

.right {
  background: yellow;
}

.right div {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.right div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row left">
    
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <div>
      Top
    </div>
    <div>
      Bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wdbrrz

Comment: @Zvesdas thanks dude, Im really appriacte ;)