# Keeping an image horizontally aligned with another image. Flexbox I don't think is the answer. I think I need some sort of scss calc()

Tags: sass, calc

I'm trying to align horizontally two images that are next to each other with different dynamic text under it. If you review the image I attached it's pretty clear what I'm trying to do. I don't think flexbox properties like flex-end or flex justify-content: space-between will work here. Thanks for your help in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYCMh.jpg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoJze.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Checkout the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568572/flexbox-vertically-split-container-in-half

Comment: I have tried to do this to the left column. display: flex; flex-direction: column;  justify-content: space-between; but because there is text underneath it aligns with the text.

Comment: Please include your code-- without it, it will be difficult for anyone to provide you with helpful direction.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution. I used calc() to achieve the results

```
position: absolute;
width: calc(100% - 50px);
margin-top: calc(112.1% - 980px / 25);
```

This calc keeps the image stuck to the image next to it. Not sure what the unit numbers mean, I basically fiddled with the units until I got the results I wanted.

Heres the result https://gifyu.com/image/vnPX