# Flexbox not wrapping items as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to create a drop down navigation menu which wraps onto two lines when it is really long.

By setting the following CSS properties on the menu I can achieve the desired result.

```
.dynamic {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This, however, does not work on Internet Explorer 11. The items do not wrap onto the next line as it does on Chrome.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/)

It will work if I use `height: 80px` instead of `max-height: 80px;` but that does not work for me as I want the menu to grow with the items.

Does anyone know how I can get IE to wrap the items properly?

Comment: IE is still buggy when max or min size is used with flexbox, but column css should work : https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/1/ (add prefix for others https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/3/ )

Comment: Yes its known bug. Check here http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @GCyrillus I tried using columns but I would want there to be one column if there are less than 4 items. Thanks though

Comment: It doesn't wrap in IE11 *and* the container doesn't expand to accommodate wrapping items in Chrome or any other browser ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/4/)). Flexbox column wrap is just not ready for prime time.

Comment: @Jackson it does form a single col with 4 li https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/9/ unless you did reset line-height or font-size where 80px won't match with 4lines https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/10/

Comment: @GCyrillus nice, I didn't see that working. I now have a problem where the container does not wrap all the items https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/11/

Comment: ?? it does, it first reaches your max-height then starts a new column, that's how column or flex column works. (column-fill:balance won't help much here either cause code relays on max-height)

Answer (score 1):

Since CSS Flexbox is not fully supported to provided a wrapping menu when the items pass a maximum height I have created a workaround using the `height` attribute.

As @Michael_B [pointed out](https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/4/), the container doesn't wrap around the wrapped items.

A solution to this is apply the background style to the flex items instead of the container [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/bnkup2ss/7/)

This allows the container 'to appear' to grow with the items. Then using the `nth-child` pseudos I can allow the last item to span the full height of the container.

```
.dynamic > li:nth-child(4n),
.dynamic > li:last-child:nth-child(n+4) {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: related: [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276)