# Make container full width with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a category dropdown menu with a few columns depending on the length of the `<ul>`.

[I've created a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/meules/wwrvy1r7/2/)

I want to place each submenu item underneath the previous one until the height of the submenu is reached. If so then everything should be placed in a new column.

Something like this:

```
Main category
 |
 subcategory1                         subcategory3
  |subsub1 for subcategroy1            |subsub1 for subcategroy3 
  |subsub2 for subcategroy1           |
 |                                    subcategory4
 subcategory2                          | etc...
  |subsub1 for subcategroy2 
  |subsub2 for subcategroy2 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------  
 // total height of the dropdown 
    is reached here
```

I'm using `flex-flow` and for that which actually works good. However I can't get my dropdown container to be full-width width a background color.

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="cats">
      <ul>

        <li class="item sub">
          <a title="Baby" href="http://ministry.webshopapp.com/baby/" class="itemLink">Baby</a>
          <div class="subnav">
            <ul class="flex-wrap">
              <li class="subitem title"><a title="Borstvoeding" href="#" class="title">something</a></li>
              <li class="subitem"><a title="ATTITUDE" href="#" class="subitemLink">ATTITUDE</a></li>
              <li class="subitem"><a title="Apple Park" href="#" class="subitemLink">Apple Park</a></li>
              <li class="subitem title"><a title="Borstvoeding" href="#" class="title">something</a></li>
              <li class="subitem"><a title="ATTITUDE" href="#" class="subitemLink">ATTITUDE</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As CSS is use this:

```
.cats .subnav {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 99;
  display:none;
}
.cats .item.sub:hover .subnav {
  display: block;
}
.flex-wrap {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
.subnav .subitem {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

SO how can I make `.subnav` to fill the background for as much needed?

Comment: it was asked a lot of times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width Short answer, You can't without JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below css code:

Add `left` and `right` to `.cats .subnav`

```
.cats .subnav {
    right: 0;
    left: 0; 
}
```

Comment: That makes the `.subnav` as wide as the `main-category` which is positioned `relative`. I tried this but doesn't work