# Jquery calculate correct container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

In regards to an earlier question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202557/make-container-full-width-with-flex) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231447/3597276)
I posted this new question since this is more Javascript related.

[Checkout my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/wwrvy1r7/)

I want to create a dropdown menu with CSS `flex`. I'm struggeling to get the container div to be as wide as the columns. With below code the calculation of the last item in the list to completely left is wrong. It looks like it's calculating the distance to the previous column.

So what I have is

```
<div class="cats">
    <ul>
        <li class="item sub">
            <a title="Baby" href="http://ministry.webshopapp.com/baby/" class="itemLink">Baby</a>
            <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="flex-wrap">
                    <li class="subitem title">
                        <a title="Borstvoeding" href="#" class="title">something</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="subitem">
                        <a title="ATTITUDE" href="#" class="subitemLink">ATTITUDE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="subitem">
                        <a title="Apple Park" href="#" class="subitemLink">Apple Park</a></li>
                    <li class="subitem title">
                        <a title="Borstvoeding" href="#" class="title">something</a>
                    </li>
                <ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.cats .subnav {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 99;
}
.cats .item.sub:hover .subnav {
  display: block;
}




.subnav .wrap{
            display:inline-flex;
            flex-flow : column wrap;
            align-content : flex-start;
            height : 350px;
            background : blue;
        }
.subitem{
    width : 150px;
    height:100px;
    background : red;
    margin : 20px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flex-wrap').each(function(index) {
        var lastChild = $(this).children().last();
        var newWidth = lastChild.position().left - $(this).position().left + lastChild.outerWidth(true);
        $(this).width(newWidth);
    });
});
```

When using it in this way it looks like it's calculating the distance to the previous column. So something like `200px` instead of `600px`. 
Can this be caused by positioning or am I doing something wrong I'am completely overlooking now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

The width of all `li` elements can't be obtained, since they are at `display:none;`.

I've made something with [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/L1k2v700/)...
You will be able to continue styling from this.
;)

Comment: Tried that but that gives the same result!

Comment: I just saw that your `.subitem` is defined to `width:150px` + `margin:20px`... Which alway will return an outerWidth of 190px. Try to remove the width definition if you want larger `li`s.

Comment: Ok, I may be completely lost here. I saw your Fiddle. Do you want to adjust the width of `flex-wrap` based on its last `subitem` ? **OR** adjust it to the same width of another `flex-wrap` (which has more or less `li` items)?

Comment: I updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/w2dy0h27/)... Is that what you want ?

Comment: Well that fiddle is actually not mine :) My fiddle is listed at thetop of this post. The set up is a bit different and I think that's why it doesn't work

Comment: Jeeezss added the wrong fiddle. Correct one is now listed

Comment: I just updated and cleaned my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/L1k2v700/)... ;)

Comment: Excellent!! So the problem is that `display:none;` avoids the script to calculate the correct size?! You've made my day!

Comment: Yes... This was the problem. ;) If you had console.logged your calculation variables... You'd seen it always returned zero... Messing all calculations. ;)