# Extend background on scrolled flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, overflow

How can I extend the background to the right using flexbox and a container with limited width?

The spans are the tags that must contain a background-color, not the parent tags. (Because the color can be different for each span)

I know that display `table` and `table-row` fixes it, but it gives me another problems with paddings and borders, so I would like to use `flexbox` model.

There is another requeriment, the background should extend to the widest span, so all spans should have the same width and extend the background to the same position.

```css
pre {
  width: 300px;
}

code {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

span {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>sadfasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdasdas  dasd as das</span>
    <span>sadfdas das adsdsad sa dasda s adsasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdas</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Since this can't be done properly in a column layout, [column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width), what issues do you have with `display: table`/`display: table-row`?

Comment: Well, figured a way that might be an option, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rearrange your CSS rules/properties a little it will work

```css
pre {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
code {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
span {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
span ~ span {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
      <span>sadfasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdasdas  dasd as das</span>
      <span>sadfdas das adsdsad sa dasda s adsasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdas</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Updated

The unwanted extra spacing that occurs in IE11/Edge (and maybe a few more) can be fixed by removing the line breaks/space in the markup

```
<pre>
  <code><span>sadfasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdasdas  dasd as das</span><span>sadfdas das adsdsad sa dasda s adsasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdas</span></code>
</pre>
```

Another option is to change the `pre`/`code` to `div`'s (tested with success on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11)

```css
div.pre {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.code {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
span ~ span {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">
  <div class="code">
      <span>sadfasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdasdas  dasd as das</span>
      <span>sadfdas das adsdsad sa dasda s adsasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdas</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FélixSanz Waiting for an answer on that .... and let me know the issue you had with `display: table` and I work out a  solution for that too, could be good if the flexbox issue can't be fixed

Comment: @FélixSanz Here is a screenshot from my IE11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z20Sa.png

Comment: @FélixSanz No, still waiting for an answer, and a fix suggestion, and since IE11 has many bugs when it comes to `flexbox` this  might not be solveable  ... meanwhile, can you let me know the issue you have with `display: table`, I have solved many things with that on IE11/10/9

Comment: If you remove whitespace inside `code` tag (no spaces between `</span>` and `<span>`) it gets fixed. Can you confirm it? Example -> https://jsfiddle.net/1o25fLyv/

Comment: @FélixSanz Yes, that take away the unwanted spacing in IE11/Edge .... as with my updated answer's 2:nd sample :)

Comment: @FélixSanz Updated ... thanks ... and I will delete comments as they no longer is needed ... agree?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:auto` to`span`

```css
pre {
  width: 300px;
}

code {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

span {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>sadfasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdasdas  dasd as das</span>
    <span>sadfdas das adsdsad sa dasda s adsasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdas</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: But that doesn't make them have the same width

Answer (score 0):

`align-items:flex-start` will help you

```css
code {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:flex-start;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

span {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>sadfasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdasdas  dasd as das</span>
    <span>sadfdas das adsdsad sa dasda s adsasdsad asd adsads  das ads dasdas</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: align-items:flex-start will help you