# Expand flexbox element to its contents?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, expand

I'm trying to use flexbox to arrange the elements below so the **div.container** and **div.right** widths to depend on the content (number of green boxes). I believe it's an issue with "flex-flow: row wrap;" that is used on **div.right**

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks!

This is my code output 
[image: My code output]

This I'm trying to achive
[image: What I'm trying to achive]

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

div.container {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #7FDBFF;
  display: flex;
}

div.left {
  background: #0074D9;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.right {
  background: #3D9970;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.right span {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #01FF70;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
    <span>11</span>
    <span>12</span>
    <span>13</span>
    <span>14</span>
    <span>15</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what should be the width of the right div?

Comment: varies depending on it's content