# flex-wrap items inside a flex container is not making the container's width bigger

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a requirement for 3 blocks of elements to look like this:

[image]

No vertical scrolling, only horizontal. To achieve this I thought I could make 3 `div.block` with the container `display: flex` then have my items inside each `.block` flex itself and wrap (note they also need to be top-bottom, left right so `flex-direction: column`)

But as you can see in this code (or [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xaVNGK)), when I do that the 3 `.block`'s widths simply refuse to expand to their content's width, even though the `.brick` do wrap they overlap each other, because the .block` just stays as big as a single column.

How can I achieve this? I feel like flex is not the right tool for the containers, but I've tried `display: inline-block` and using a `table` with 3 `td`s which does the exact same thing.

I'm not sure how to get the `.container` to increase in width as more content goes in and get the `.block` to increase as well.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.brick {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.brick-red {
  background: red;
}
  
.brick-blue {
  background: blue;
}
  
.brick-orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's seems an overflow issue and the item aren't expanding their width .. increase the z-index of the first one for example and you will see that red block were behind the blue

Comment: Have you tried using `flex: 1`  or just `flex-grow: 1` on the brick containers to have them expand?

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that I want the blocks to only take as much space as their content allows. Putting `flex: 1` will make them all take as much space as one another.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width may help

Comment: @ExplosionPills That does help thanks, it seems just not doable!

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the width or the flex-basis to be the total width of your content including margins, and set the flex-shrink to 0.

Try setting

```
.block {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 0 calc(110px * 3); 
  //calc can be replaced with a fixed value if you're doing a px based approach
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 calc(110px * 3);
}

.brick {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.brick-red {
  background: red;
}

.brick-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.brick-orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
    <div class="brick brick-orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain why?

Comment: Try running your changes in codepen; it does not look like his requirements

Comment: So that kind of works, but the items now have a lot of space between one another and it still overlaps if the container is smaller (say 400opx)

Comment: @ExplosionPills based on the post his requirements were to simply expand the width of each block to their content using flex which I've done.
Modifying the flex percentage should adjust the spacing, but I'll re-test

Comment: @LanFeusT check the updated version, it will work, given your requirements, but for a more responsive, scalable approach you might want to consider using relative units instead of absolute ones like these.