# Dynamic width parent with flexbox column wrapping?

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns, col

Parent has only `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, while children have a fixed `height` and `width` of `150px`. Which behaves like this:

[image]

The height of the parent container expands vertically to facilitate the wrapping children elements.

However, changing the parent to have `flex-direction: column` doesn't have the same behaviour horizontally:

[image]

Instead of the parent expanding to fit the wrapping content, it's the children elements that get rearranged to be facilitated within the parent element.

The behaviour I'd like to achieve with the vertically wrapping content looks like this:

[image]

Well almost like this. Imagine the parent fills the space vertically, and expands horizontally for the wrapping content. A horizontal version of the first gif.

Is this possible with flex-box?

Comment: Note that in most cases elements are set, by default, to `height: auto`. This means the height of the element is the height of the content. But this behavior does not apply to the width of block-level elements, which is set, by default, to the full width of the parent (think: `width: 100%`). That's one why you're seeing different behaviors in `row` and `column` directions ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)). For other reasons, see the duplicate posts.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `align-content: start` (it deprecated `flex-start` so grid and flexbox get unified syntax):

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: start;
}
span {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #f66;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #f66;
  font: italic 2.1em sans-serif;
  padding: .21em;
}
body {
  background-color: #f95b68;
}
body { margin: 0;}
* {box-sizing: border-box}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
  <span>11</span>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>13</span>
  <span>14</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful in fixing the gaps between elements, although the main issue I'm having is that the parent container doesn't adjust to facilitate the wrapping columns, like it does when wrapping rows. Edit: after further research I've found this is a deficiency in the flex layout, and not possible with plain css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width

The issue I'm having was addressed in this post. Simply the parent container doesn't expand in width when columns get wrapped (whereas when rows are wrapped, the parent container expands downwards with no problem).

Quote: "This looks like a fundamental deficiency in flex layout. A flex container in column-direction will not expand to accommodate additional columns. (This is not a problem in flex-direction: row.)"

Comment: That's clearly not what I understood from your question. Glad you found your answer. I'll delete my answer tomorrow. Already reached the deletion quota for the day. Cheers!

Comment: That's alright. Your explanation makes sense as to why this would be an issue. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Looking into it, I'd expect changing `<div>`'s display value from `flex` to `inline-flex` to have the effect you're looking for. However, it remains at the width of 1 column. Looks more like a bug to me.