# How to use column-fill to auto without setting fixed height?

Tags: html, css

I am currently in a situation where I need to do use multi-column layout mode of css.

Basically, I am creating a mega-menu where I need to have variable list items inside unordered list.

For that I need to have four columns and if content from list items are not far enough to fit within four columns, it should just stay within one column. That's why I need to have flexible height on multi-column container.

```
<ul class="megamenu-list">
    <li>Item-1</li>
    <li>Item-2</li>
    <li>Item-3</li>
</ul>
```

and here is the css part.

```
.megamenu-list {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  column-count: 4;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

After some googling I come to know that to be able to use **column-fill** auto, one needs to have constrained(fixed) height on parent container which is not useful as there may be the case when there are only one or two list items within container.

I already tried that thing in my other question with flex but with no luck of getting any response.

[Set flex container height to flex items content height when there are only fewer items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320266/set-flex-container-height-to-flex-items-content-height-when-there-are-only-fewer)

Now I found the below discussion at github which seems to be closed but don't know how.

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3064

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need javascript for this. CSS can't count items for you and style based on that count.

Comment: Yes but after counting items what will I have?

Comment: You'll know whether to apply `column-count:4` or not.

Comment: Without setting column-count I can't get the content into second column, so column-count is indeed necessary.

Comment: My point is that you only need to create a second column if you have nore than 4 items...which is why you need to count them...using javascript.

Comment: Ahh you are not getting me. It is not necessary to have one item per one column. My question is that if the height of column exceeds the certain value then it should be moved to second column. There can also be three items in first column and also no item at all in second column.

Comment: There is no CSS method of doing that dynamically. Either you have a set number of rows or a set number of columns.

Comment: This is indeed a javascript issue, or other programming language issue. you need to format the html to fit your requirements of the layout.