# Resizing an HTML dialog tag horizontally with contents that wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, dialog

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJZJaa)

I have an HTML `dialog` tag full of content. I want the content to respond to its container's height, wrapping to create a new column when the content is larger than the container. I have boundaries on how tall the container can be, as well, for aesthetic reasons

I'm accomplishing this with `flex-flow: column wrap` and that works fine to make the contents create a new column, but the containing dialog isn't resizing to contain it. Is there a way to make the `dialog` tag grow to encompass the contents as they flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem: [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width)

tl;dr- Current browsers do not horizontally expand flex containers  which have `flex: column wrap` set, although they do expand vertically for `flex: row wrap`

Comment: I guess you can mark the linked thread as a duplicate to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `max-height` CSS property in `vh` units (vertical height, where 100 is full window height). [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLrLBW)

```css
.country-selector-stylized-dialog .country-selector-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 10em;
  max-height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
  <dialog class="country-selector-stylized-dialog" open="">
    <div class="country-selector-container">
      <div class="country-selector-item country-selector-current-item"> Ireland </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Australia </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> België </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Brazil </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Canada </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Danmark </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Deutschland </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> España </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> France </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> India </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Italia </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Nederland </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> New Zealand </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Norge </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Österreich </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Schweiz </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Singapore </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Suomi </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> Sverige </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> United Kingdom </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> United States </div>
      <div class="country-selector-item"> 日本 </div>
    </div>
  </dialog>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have resized the dialog.

Comment: It worked for me in Chrome 75

Comment: What I'm seeing is just the dialog at the same size, with the content off to the right

Comment: @ABMagil, you didn't mention anything about a horizontal constraint.But the content does create new columns as specified when the vertical shrinks.

Comment: "Is there a way to make the dialog tag grow to encompass the contents as they flow?"

I need the dialog tag to grow, not the .country-selector-container