# Can't force flex column container to full height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There's a boxed timeline that contains 5 columns. So far it renders fine. However, when adding more columns it becomes stretched due to height overflow of their parent container.

```
<section id="timeline">
    <div class="demo-card-wrapper">
        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step1">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>01</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Technology</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step2">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>02</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Confidence</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step3">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>03</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Adaptation</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step4">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>04</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Consistency</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step5">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>05</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Conversion</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step6"> <!-- Added this -->
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>05</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Conversion</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>    


        <div class="demo-card demo-card--step7"> <!-- And this  -->
            <div class="head">
                <div class="number-box">
                    <span>05</span>
                </div>
                <h2><span class="small">Subtitle</span> Conversion</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```

[Here's the original demo](https://codepen.io/paulhbarker/pen/apvGdv/)

The thing is that the container might contain more than 100 columns, so it must be able to store an unlimited number of columns.

[Here's the modified demo with 2 added columns.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoaMJg)

I've tried to play with height by setting it 100%, auto, but none of that helped.

So the question is, why setting a height to 100% doesn't work?

Comment: I'm seeing a width problem, not a height problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Michael_B The width problem is caused by height overflow of the initial parent container

Comment: Maybe. But you should take a look at this post for a known `column wrap` problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done via pure CSS, so I had to tweak column orders and container height via some JavaScript. The logic has been taken from the original source file.

```
$(function(){

    var items = $(".demo-card").length;
    var rows = Math.ceil(items / 2);
    var counter = items - rows + 2;
    var y = counter;

    // Count column order
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        var odd = (i + 1) * 2  - 1 ;
        var even = (i + 1) * 2;

        $(`.demo-card:nth-child(${odd})`).css('order', i + 1);
        $(`.demo-card:nth-child(${even})`).css('order', y);

        y++;
    }

    // Count container height
    var stagger = 180;
    var cardHeight = 450;
    var outerMargin = 90;
    var containerHeight = rows * (cardHeight + outerMargin) + stagger;

    $(".demo-card-wrapper").css('height', containerHeight + 'px');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to adapt the $item variable in your css to match your actual items in the timeline:

```
$items: 7;
```

see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeoqJq

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned in the original post, there might an unlimited number of items, so it must be able to handle new items dynamically.

Comment: your need javascript for that. just to the calculation in javascript then.