# writing-mode: initial != horizontal-tb at chrome

Tags: css

If the parent element writing-mode = vertical-lr, then the writing-mode values in the child elements, initial and horizontal-tb, show different styles

```
.pop_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    height: 100%;
    .pop_menu_item {
      display: inline-block;
      flex-basis: 35%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      writing-mode: initial;
    }
  }
```

[writing-mode](https://jsrun.pro/AjWKp/edit)

Comment: do you actually need to concern yourself with writing mode? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When flex-direction=column, the width of the element does not automatically increase（https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709）, so you can use writing-mode=vertical-lr to achieve the layout of the flex-direction=column, so let the child element writing-mode= horizontal-tb to ensure the following layout is normal

Comment: there must be some code stopping the flex column width from automatically increasing because it is normal for it to do so.

Comment: In fact, it was considered a bug(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709), I don't care about that, I wonder why initial and horizontal-tb didn't look the same(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)