# How can I push my columns wrap fixed height further

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

Hi and thank to click on this question,

I made a fixed height column with flex and wrap and would have the parent div with a following width. (the parent div stop at the end of the body?)

currently the columns go outside of my parent div

what I am missing in my code ?
I'm sure it's so simple :/

```
<style>ul#list {
font-family: sans-serif;
list-style: none;
background: #dddddd;
height: 200px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
flex-flow: column wrap;  
border: 8px solid #121212;
padding: 10px;
}

li {
position: relative;
display: block;
width:300px;
color: #232323;
background: #eee;
padding: 6px 10px;
margin: 4px;
border: 1px dotted #121212;
border-radius: 10px;
}</style>

<div id="outer">
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item #1</li>
    <li>Item #2</li>
    <li>Item #3</li>
    <li>Item #4</li>
    <li>Item #5</li>
    <li>Item #6</li>
    <li>Item #7</li>
    <li>Item #8</li>
    <li>Item #9</li>
    <li>Item #10</li>
    <li>Item #11</li>
    <li>Item #12</li>        
    <li>Item #13</li>
    <li>Item #14</li>
    <li>Item #15</li>
    <li>Item #16</li>
    <li>Item #17</li>
    <li>Item #18</li>
    <li>Item #19</li>
    <li>Item #20</li>
    <li>Item #21</li>
    <li>Item #22</li>
    <li>Item #23</li>
    <li>Item #24</li>
    <li>Item #25</li>
    <li>Item #26</li>
    <li>Item #27</li>
    <li>Item #28</li>
    <li>Item #29</li>
    <li>Item #30</li>
    <li>Item #31</li>
    <li>Item #32</li>      
</ul>
</div>
```

thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question have already an answer here :

[When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width)

This look like been a recurrent problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you question right, I got it like, that you want to hide everything that's overlapping the parent div?

If so, on your parent div add following css property:

`overflow-x: hidden;`

This way everything that's outside of your parent div will be hidden. Keep in mind, that the black border will still be behind your child items.

Comment: thanks, hoargarth, it's the inverse, I want the parent div following the li overflow : )

Answer (score 0):

You Need to give width of 'li' according to your parent 'ul' width

Comment: thanks Yash for your first comment, I would the inverse, have the ul following the li overflow