# flex-wrap doesn't work for columns when align-items set to any other value than stretched

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When box-container have `align-items: flex-start` boxes marked as `b3` and `b4` do not want to wrap items they contain. Why is it?

If you remove the line, wrapping works (bonus question, why items don't stretch parent container?)

```css
#box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* !!! */
}

.box {
  min-width: 135px;
  min-height: 135px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* переносит на следующую строку/столбец элемент, если мало места */
  align-content: flex-start;
  /* выравнивание рядов по вертикали */
  justify-items: flex-start;
  /* выравнивание столбцов по горизонтали */
}

#b1 {
  background-color: hsl(0, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: row;
}

#b2 {
  background-color: hsl(90, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#b3 {
  background-color: hsl(180, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: column;
}

#b4 {
  background-color: hsl(270, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.smallbox {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* выравнивание содержимого по вертикали */
  justify-content: center;
  /* выравнивание содержимого по горизонтали */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSSFlexbox Main Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="box-container">
    <div id="b1" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(0, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(30, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(60, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b2" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(90, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(120, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(150, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b3" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(180, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(210, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(240, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b4" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(270, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(300, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(330, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `stretch` (which is the default alignment) make the `b3` `b4` have full height of their parent container which is a needed constraint in order to have a wrapping. Without stretch you will simply have a, overflow since there is no height contraint. Inspect the element in both cases and you will notice that:

1. With stretch the height is variable **based on the parent** container which is the screen size
2. without stretch (when you define `align-items: flex-start`) the height is fixed **based on the content** (the 3 boxes inside)

---

You can get a similar behavior with `b1` and `b2` if you disable the default shrink effect:

```css
#box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* !!! */
}

.box {
  min-width: 135px;
  min-height: 135px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* переносит на следующую строку/столбец элемент, если мало места */
  align-content: flex-start;
  /* выравнивание рядов по вертикали */
  justify-items: flex-start;
  /* выравнивание столбцов по горизонтали */
}

#b1 {
  background-color: hsl(0, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

#b2 {
  background-color: hsl(90, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

#b3 {
  background-color: hsl(180, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: column;
}

#b4 {
  background-color: hsl(270, 25%, 50%);
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.smallbox {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* выравнивание содержимого по вертикали */
  justify-content: center;
  /* выравнивание содержимого по горизонтали */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSSFlexbox Main Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="box-container">
    <div id="b1" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(0, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(30, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(60, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b2" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(90, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(120, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(150, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b3" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(180, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(210, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(240, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b4" class="box">
      <div class="smallbox sb1" style="background-color:hsla(270, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb2" style="background-color:hsla(300, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox sb3" style="background-color:hsla(330, 50%, 50%);">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Having `flex-shrink:0` there is no width contraint so the item will have the width of its content, no more shrinking and no more wrapping.

---

For your bonus question check this: [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/8620333)

Comment: setting `align-self: stretch` to `b3` and `b4` fixed it for me