# Absolute Flex container not changing to the correct width with defined max-height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to break a flexbox column container after every 4th element. For that I defined a max-height, since I know the height of every element.

```css
.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

li:nth-child(4n) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="subnav">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The flex container renders its child elements correctly, but the actual size of the container (grey area) is smaller. Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Result for me:
[image: Rendered Image]

Comment: Bro Just add the ```padding: 0;``` in ```ul``` and your problem will get solved. Let me know if this is what you wanted !?

Comment: @KunalTanwar No, this is not my problem. The problem is, that 5,6 and 7 are not in the grey box, even though they should be from my understanding.

Thanks for the note, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width

Comment: Oh! Well did you solve your problem??

Comment: No, it seems to be a limitation for all major browsers, that this is not possible.