# flex-wrap in column direction flex - Container not adapting the width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't know what silliness I've got myself into but I'm stuck in a common flexbox issue..

Here's a pen.. https://codepen.io/webdev51/pen/zYPWwbd

What I'm trying to achieve is the parent flex div to be adapting the width when flex item go into 2nd row using `flex-wrap`.

**Desired/expected result:**

[image]

**Results I get:**

[image]

And here's the most important part that is driving me nuts.

If I replicate the same in `flex-direction: row;` , it'll be working as expected and whenever the items drop in the next row, the container will adapt the height accordingly.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: @Sunderam I've already shared the pen

Comment: This seems to be known strange behaviour of Flex and I see this question has passed multiple times. Below topic bundles multiple examples and workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width There are some possible workarounds in there you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score -1):

after changing `display: inline-flex` to `display: flex`, add `align-content: flex-start;`

```css
.spaceship-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 90vh;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid orange;
}

    .spaceship {
      height: 240px;
      width: 290px;
      position: relative;
      border:1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="spaceship-group">
  <div class="spaceship"></div>
  <div class="spaceship"></div>
  <div class="spaceship"></div>
  <div class="spaceship"></div>
  <div class="spaceship"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the ccontainer width to be 100% of the screen. That's what flex does