# CSS property "writing-mode: vertical-lr" has issues with flex-box in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having an interesting issue where I am building a dynamic navigation menu that is not rendering its contents correctly in Firefox (v114.01). It renders fine on both Edge (v114.0.1823.43) and Chrome (v114.0.5735.134).

It seems like the "writing-mode: vertical-lr" property is being applied differently in Firefox.

The reason why I am using writing-mode is to overcome the issue of flex box wrapped columns not growing its width [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width). Again, this seems to work fine in Edge/Chrome but not Firefox.

Here is a code pen with an example: https://codepen.io/Jean-Paul-Larach/pen/vYQNRPY

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  max-width: 90vw;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  >div {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}

.groupHeader {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  font-style: italic;
}

.section {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

.navMenuLink {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.header {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  max-height: 55vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="padding-right: 15px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="group">
        <h3 class="groupHeader">Groups</span>
        </h3>
        <div>
          <div class="section">
            <h4><span><b>Group 1</b></span></h4>
          </div><a class="navMenuLink">Child 1</a>
          <div class="section">
            <h4><span><b>Group 2</b></span></h4>
          </div><a class="navMenuLink">Child 1</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 2</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 3</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 4</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 5</a>
          <div class="section">
            <h4><span><b>Group 3</b></span></h4>
          </div><a class="navMenuLink">Child 1</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 2</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 3</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 4</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 5</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 6</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 7</a>
          <div class="section">
            <h4><span><b>Group 4</b></span></h4>
          </div><a class="navMenuLink">Child 1</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div role="separator" aria-orientation="vertical"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3 class="groupHeader"><span>Sites</span></h3>
        <div>
          <div class="section">
            <h4><span><b>Group 1</b></span></h4>
          </div><a class="navMenuLink">Child 1</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 2</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 3</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 4</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 5</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 6</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 7</a>
          <a class="navMenuLink">Child 8</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 9</a><a class="navMenuLink">Child 10</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edge Screenshot:**
[image: Edge]

**Firefox Screenshot:**
[image: Firefox]

Any guidance or feedback will be much appreciated!

I tried to change my code to use other types of layouts but that presented many challenges. Flexbox should be the choice for creating navigation.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I've filed [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1848512) in the hope that it will fix the issue described.

I had some weird issues in Firefox with nested flex elements and vertical writing-mode in the past.
Take a look at [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/glmvc/pen/LYdErxy) in Firefox, which is a minimal setup, and you will see that Firefox has problems with the content size of the nested flex parent. It looks like this is actually a **bug in Firefox**.

#### To address your case and problem:

1. You're using CSS nesting. Note that this is only [supported from Firefox Version 117](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting), which is not yet available to most users (as of today).
2. I don't think that using `inline-flex` is essential for your goals, so I changed the inline flex elements to `flex`.
3. As I mentioned above, it seems that Firefox is buggy with nested flex elements and writing-mode set to vertical.

   - Usually it's fine to use `display: grid;` instead of `flex` for one of the container elements, because in most cases you can achieve the same result with CSS Grid. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work with Grid in your particular case.
   - I found that disabling and re-enabling the `flex-flow` property in Firefox's dev tools somehow fixes the problem. My guess is that this is triggering a style recalculation in the browser. So I wrote the following JavaScript that reproduces this behavior of disabling and re-enabling a CSS property by removing the property and adding it back to the appropriate elements:

```js
function fixFlexBug() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".group > div");

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    const flexFlowValue = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("flex-flow");

    // temporarily reset the "flex-flow" property to "initial"
    element.style.flexFlow = "initial";

    // trigger a reflow by accessing the offsetWidth property
    // this ensures that changes to styles are immediately applied
    void element.offsetWidth;

    // restore the original "flex-flow" property value
    element.style.flexFlow = flexFlowValue;
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", fixFlexBug);
```

I know that this is a very **hacky solution**, but it seems to fix the issue in Firefox; at least for now...

---

Here is the adapted CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width: 90vw;
}

.header {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  max-height: 55vh;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.groupHeader {
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    font-style: italic;
 }

.section {
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
 }

.navMenuLink {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
```