# Flexbox breaks with nested flex containers and writing-mode vertical-lr in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, cross-browser

I'm experiencing a problem in Firefox when using vertical writing mode combined with two nested flex containers. Specifically, the second flex container doesn't expand to contain its children, breaking the layout.

[image]

I've checked [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310551) bug report on Bugzilla, which seems related, but couldn't find any workarounds there.
This problem sounds similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76468014/css-property-writing-mode-vertical-lr-has-issues-with-flex-box-in-firefox), but my error is coming when two flex elements are nested inside each other.

Context

- I'm creating a marquee with horizontally rendered list items.
- Each list item is within a flex container. I clone this list, using another flex container to keep these elements aligned horizontally.
- However, in Firefox, the nested flex containers don't behave as expected when using writing-mode: vertical-lr.

I considered using the @-moz-document url-prefix() selector for Firefox-specific styles, attempting to replicate the vertical writing mode with text rotation. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue of text not expanding to fill its parent.

Additionally, I explored the possibility of changing one of the flex items to a grid layout as suggested in a Stack Overflow discussion [CSS property "writing-mode: vertical-lr" has issues with flex-box in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76468014/css-property-writing-mode-vertical-lr-has-issues-with-flex-box-in-firefox), but this approach didn't yield the desired results either.

Could anyone suggest any workarounds or solutions to fix this issue in Firefox, particularly for a layout with nested flex containers and vertical writing mode?

Here is a reproduction. If you open this in firefox and inspect the `secondFlex` item you will notice it has collapsed.

```css
.title {
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.titleClone {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.link {
  display: grid;
  background: green;
  border: black solid 1px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
.secondFlex {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.firstFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstFlex">
  <div class='secondFlex'>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='title'>Titler</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='title'>Shorter Title</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='title'>This is a much longer title and will wrap into m</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='title'>This is a really long title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='title'>This is a really long artist title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='secondFlex'>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='titleClone'>Titler</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='titleClone'>Shorter Title</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='titleClone'>This is a much longer title and will wrap into m</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='titleClone'>This is a really long title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="link">
      <h2 class='titleClone'>This is a really long artist title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modify your html and css code structure for solve your problem i hope useful this code.:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
li{list-style: none;}

.title {
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.titleClone {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: white;
}
.link {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background: green;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstFlex">
<ul class='secondFlex'>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='title'>Titler</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='title'>Shorter Title</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='title'>This is a much longer title and will wrap into m</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='title'>This is a really long title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='title'>This is a really long artist title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class='secondFlex'>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='titleClone'>Titler</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='titleClone'>Shorter Title</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='titleClone'>This is a much longer title and will wrap into m</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='titleClone'>This is a really long title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="link">
    <h2 class='titleClone'>This is a really long artist title that will wrap into multiple lines</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However, one requirement is that I keep two of the secondFlex inner divs. I need the firstFlex div to have at least two children, because the secondFlex divs are cloned to make a marquee. Is there a way to make your example work with two inner divs with no line wrapping? So it stays in one continuous line

Comment: I have modified this code please check again

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Your solution involves assigning fixed heights to the link elements. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to adapt the heights to be responsive, similar to the approach demonstrated in the updated example. Additionally, is it possible to prevent the link elements from wrapping, akin to the behavior in a flexbox layout? Ideally, these elements should occupy the full height of the first flex container, which might have variable heights.

Could you suggest modifications to achieve this?