# Fixed flex parent with wrap doesn't expand to fit content on Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a ul with fixed positioning and flex wrap columns and child li elements with a fixed width. The width of the ul expands when it wraps to fit a large number of li as the content on Chrome, but it is not working on Firefox and Safari. How can I force the ul to expand to fit the contents on Firefox and Safari?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
  <li class="child">item</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using `width: fit-content` on the parent `ul` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: FWIW even on Chrome if you resize your browsers height to smaller the child elements "escape"  the parent...

Comment: I don't have those other browsers handy ATM but perhaps change the parent to `height: 100vh;`

Comment: This is a good question. I have been fiddling with this for an hour and can't seem to figure out why Firefox and Chrome differ on this. What's really interesting is that Firefox doesn't do this behavior if you have flexbox row and a set a 100% width, so I'm not sure why it would act this way for flexbox column and a 100% height